# Why does the code in c not end and forces me to press crl+z to end the execution?

Tags: c

I´ve made a simple code to print in reverse the numbers written between letters.
For example: if I write on the terminal:
1 2 3 hello 4 5 6 end
or enter that in the function through a txt its returning the expected values:
3 2 1\n
6 5 4\n
but it doesn´t end, Im forced to press crl+z to be able to use the trminal again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_NUM 64

int main() {
    int num[MAX_NUM];
    int size = 0, i;
    char word[20];
    while (scanf("%d", &num[size]) != 0) {
        size++;
        while(scanf("%d", &num[size]) != 0){
            size++;
        }
        if (scanf("%s",word) != 0 || size == MAX_NUM) {
            for (i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if(i == 0)
                    printf("%d", num[i]);
                else
                    printf("%d ", num[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            size = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to insert some simple print statements to see how the program executes?

Comment: Hint: try the input `1 2 3 hello 4 5 6 end bye` or any other letter after `end`

Comment: To put it differently... The program does not require ctrl-z to terminate. Any input not being an integer will end the program.

Comment: Which OS? Do you execute the program in a terminal or inside some IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the code in c not end and forces me to press crl+z to end the execution?

Because `scanf` cannot read your mind.  For instance, when you call `scanf("%d", &num[size])` and there is not presently any more data available to read, `scanf` doesn't know that you don't intend ever to present any more.  Before it returns, it needs to see an end-of-input or error signal or a character that it cannot match to the format.  In Windows, Ctrl-Z signals end-of-input on the standard input of a program running in the terminal.

Comment: So true thanks, just changing the != 0 to == 1 in the first while did it, thank u

Comment: @LucasRusGallego You write: " just changing the != 0 to == 1 in the first while did it" That sounds weird and wrong!

Comment: "In Windows, Ctrl-Z signals end-of-input on the standard input of a program running in the terminal." Correct but... EOF can't end the program posted by OP.  If the program receives EOF it will be an endless loop. I wonder if OP is on *nix an don't fully understand the difference between ending a program and suspending a program

Answer (score 1):

> Im forced to press crl+z to be able to use the trminal again.

Then you can't be running on Windows. On Windows ctrl-z in a terminal means EOF (End Of File). If your program receives an EOF freom a `scanf` call it will enter an endless loop.

But you do write:

> Im forced to press crl+z to be able to use the terminal again.

In that case you are on a *nix system (or a similar system). On *nix ctrl-z means "suspend". It will give you the terminal prompt back but it will not end the program. The program is still there in the background. Run `pidof <program-name>` to see that.

Some comments about your program:

```
while(scanf(...) != 0)
```

is nearly always bad (perhaps always bad). The reason is that you can't catch an EOF with such code.

The better way is

```
while(scanf(...) == N)
```

where N is the number of items you expect to scan (it's 1 in your case). By doing that EOF will work.

Code like

```
scanf("%s",word)
```

is always bad - very bad. The user may overflow the buffer. Always limit the maximum number of characters to read. In your case like:

```
scanf("%19s",word)
```

However, fixing the above won't make the program end when you give input like

```
1 2 3 hello 4 5 6 end
```

The program will call the outer (first) `scanf("%d", &num[size])` and wait forever because it doesn't receive further input.

You can end your program by giving it two consecutive non-integer inputs. Example

```
1 2 3 hello 4 5 6 end abc
                      ^
                      This will cause outer scanf to return zero
                      and the program will stop
```

If you want "end" to mean "end the program", you can add code like:

```
if (strcmp(word, "end") == 0) return 0;
```